# Why doesn't dovecot accept a SSL certificate?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, dovecot

I trying to setup a mail server on my server, I followed the following instructions:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html
```

but in the system log I am sill getting the following error:

```
Sep 25 14:00:38 tanko-20590 dovecot: managesieve-login: Fatal: Can't load certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem: The file doesn't contain a cer$
Sep 25 14:00:38 tanko-20590 dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: Can't load certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem: The file doesn't contain a certificat$
Sep 25 14:00:38 tanko-20590 dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: Can't load certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem: The file doesn't contain a certificat$
Sep 25 14:00:38 tanko-20590 dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Can't load certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem:
```

Comment: Isn't the message clear? There is no certificate in the file /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem.

Comment: It's clear but how can I create one? Sorry id this is a stupid question but i'm not a server administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup a SSL mail server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/38053/how-do-i-setup-a-ssl-mail-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `tinyca2` to create my certificates.  It is available as a package. In Ubuntu you may want to add `dovecot` to the `ssl-cert` group.  This will allow it to read certificates from the standard directories. Try using the following command.

```
adduser dovecot ssl-cert
```

You will also want to ensure the `ssl-cert` group can read the key for the certificate.

```
chgrp ssl-cert /etc/ssl/cert/ssl-mail-key.pem
```

Normally your certificate goes in `/etc/ssl/certs` and the key in `/etc/ssl/private`.

Answer (score 1):

The creation and configuration of certificates for Dovecot is documented in the [Wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/CertificateCreation).

If you followed the instructions and it still does not work then we need way more information than "it does not work".